# sql sort by joined column and paging very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query:

```
WITH O AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Advertisers.advertiser_title asc) as 'num', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY spot_date asc) as 'num2',product_title,advertiser_title,brand_title,sector_title,channel_title,copy_title,prog_title,clipType_title,Spots_tv.spot_id,Spots_tv.spot_date,Spots_tv.time_start,Spots_tv.time_end,Spots_tv.clipppos_id,Spots_tv.prog_id,Spots_tv.channel_id,Spots_tv.copy_id,Spots_tv.duration,official_cost FROM Spots_tv 
RIGHT JOIN Copies_tv ON Copies_tv.copy_id = Spots_tv.copy_id 
RIGHT JOIN ClipPositions ON ClipPositions.clippos_id = Spots_tv.clipppos_id 
RIGHT JOIN Programmes ON Programmes.prog_id = Spots_tv.prog_id 
RIGHT JOIN Channels ON Channels.channel_id = Spots_tv.channel_id 
RIGHT JOIN Products ON Products.product_id = Copies_tv.product_id 
RIGHT JOIN ClipTypes ON ClipTypes.cliptype_id = Copies_tv.cliptype_id 
RIGHT JOIN Advertisers ON Advertisers.advertiser_id = Products.advertiser_id 
RIGHT JOIN Brands ON Brands.brand_id = Products.brand_id 
RIGHT JOIN Classes ON Classes.class_id = Products.class_id 
RIGHT JOIN Producers ON Producers.producer_id = Brands.producer_id 
RIGHT JOIN Categories ON Categories.category_id = Classes.category_id 
RIGHT JOIN Sectors ON Sectors.sector_id = Categories.sector_id
WHERE Advertisers.advertiser_id IN (1640311,1640315,1640330) AND Spots_tv.spot_date BETWEEN '2014-3-20' AND '2015-3-20' ) 

SELECT O.spot_id,O.channel_id,O.copy_id,O.duration,O.official_cost,product_title,O.spot_date,advertiser_title,brand_title,sector_title,channel_title,copy_title,prog_title,clipType_title,O.time_start,O.time_end FROM O 
WHERE O.num2 BETWEEN 1 AND 15 ORDER BY O.num2 ASC
```

Sub query, it works very fast, there is 11000+ rows in subquery and there should be more than million soon, and full query needs less than a second, but if i change

```
WHERE O.num2 BETWEEN 1 AND 15 ORDER BY O.num2 ASC
```

with

```
WHERE O.num BETWEEN 1 AND 15 ORDER BY O.num ASC
```

It needs more than 14 seconds, why is so big difference ? i know sorting by string is slower but, what can i do to speed up this query ?

sorry for bad english

Comment: go for pagination feature if you are using sql 2008 or above

Comment: do you mean OFFSET ? it is not supported in 2008, and im using 2008